# Is this Cryptography method secure for a Windows App?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core

I'm creating a library to do some REST API calls that is using OAuth2. I would like to cache the refresh token so the user doesn't have to re-authenticate at every log in, although I know almost nothing about cryptography. Microsoft Docs say that for small pieces of data like strings, asymmetric crypto is the way to go. Here is my class to store the encrypted token on a file somewhere on the computer (specified by the calling code). It works, I'm just not sure how secure it is.

```cs
string _file;
const string _containerName = "MyTokenCache";

public EncryptedTokenCache(string fileLocation)
{
    _file = fileLocation;
}


public void SaveToken(string token)
{
    var rsa = CreateRSAProvider(_containerName);
    var encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    WriteToFile(encryptedData);
}

public string GetToken()
{
    var rsa = CreateRSAProvider(_containerName);
    var encryptedData = ReadFromFile();
    var decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedData, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
}


private RSA CreateRSAProvider(string containerName)
{
    CspParameters parameters = new CspParameters
    {
        KeyContainerName = containerName
    };
    return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);
}

private void WriteToFile(byte[] data)
{
    using(var fs = new FileStream(_file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}

private byte[] ReadFromFile()
{
    byte[] data;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(_file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    {
        data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: In general answer to any such question is "no secure". Maybe you are asking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection

Comment: There's no such thing as secure code, just code that is not-yet-determined to be insecure. It takes years to become a security expert to find insecurities. If you really want secure code then go pay an expert to help you. I don't want to besmirch anyone here, but any answer you get to this question that says your code is secure is only as good as the experience of the person answering - and that you don't readily know.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you, this particular code doesn't need to be extra super secure, just more secure than storing it as plain text. My main concern was that the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` was correctly creating/dealing with the keys under the covers.

Comment: So your implementation basically follows the code provided by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACryptoServiceProvider__ctor_System_Security_Cryptography_CspParameters_

Essentially, the risk is that the underlying CSP changes such that the keys can no longer be retrieved. Depending on versions of Windows, hardware, AD membership, the actual storage location and security to the keys may change.

Comment: So your risk is really the user upgrading windows one day will be unable to decrypt the data you stored. Due to the code you used, an attack here would be most likely angled at Windows and the interop in the .net framework, not specific code that you ship as part of your app (except for the fact, of course, that the attacker would be able to see what you use as 'Container Name' plain text)

Comment: @zaitsman Thank you for your clarification. In the case that the data is lost, I'll just have the user sign in normally. That would be more of on inconvenience than anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just RSA / PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption. In principle you'd better use OAEP because it is:

1. provable secure and
2. less vulnerable to padding oracle attacks.

But for storing tokens PKCS#1 v1.5 should be fine.

Furthermore, you could use symmetric encryption using AES as well, as you currently create the key pair each time you create your class. That means that the private key is available at the same location as the public key, so the security that asymmetric crypto brings is not directly used. That said, I don't see any pressing need to use AES instead for this particular use case.

Comment: The token is coming back from an OAuth response, which is json.

Comment: The only other padding type that works is `RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1`, the others give CryptographicExceptions

Comment: SHA-1 is fine for OAEP really, MGF1 (the mask generation function in OAEP) doesn't really care about SHA-1 or what hash is used. The only trick is trying to explain it to an auditor :)